# Angular cli issue (ng new/ng serve, etc..) ng commands not working on Windows

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, command-line-interface

None of the ng commads are working anymore in my terminal. I can't generate a new projet ng new ... not working anymore, nor ng serve, etc...

This is the error I get for ng serve/ ng new ... ng --v,

"bash: /c/Users/Dragos/AppData/Roaming/npm/ng: /bin/sh: bad interpreter: No such file or directory"

It's as if the ng commands are not working at all.

I reinstalled node/npm/angular CLI globally and still I get the same error.

I am on windows 8.1 pro.

Sorry if the question is duplicate, I haven't seen a question asking for this specific piece of info.

Thanks

Comment: Are you running in linux or windows?

Comment: Oh sorry, windows 8.1 pro will edit the question thanks for pointing it.

Comment: Hmmm, and you're running these commands from the normal Windows command prompt or powershell? Because for some reason `bash` is running, which is the linux/unix shell

Comment: Initially I tried from the visual studio code integrated terminal, then I tried from windows cmd line and from bash, still getting same error. It's as if bash is running under the hood but I did not launch it specifically, can it run by itself without me launching it? But I think in VS code bash is the default integrated terminal right? However, up until now it worked just fine from the VS code terminal. But not anymore.

Comment: Does the file `c:\Users\Dragos\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng` exist? Can you read its content?

Comment: I say 'from vs code" and then 'from bash" because the 2nd time I tried opening gitbash directly in the directory where I wanted to generate the angular project without using the VS code terminal.

Comment: It has no specific filetype but if I open it in notepad ++ here's what it contains: 
#!/bin/sh
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")

case `uname` in
    *CYGWIN*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
esac

if [ -x "$basedir/node" ]; then
  "$basedir/node"  "$basedir/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng" "$@"
  ret=$?
else 
  node  "$basedir/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng" "$@"
  ret=$?
fi
exit $ret

Comment: The first line is `#!/bin/sh`. The `#!` is called a shebang in unix systems and is used to indicate what program to run the script with, in this case `/bin/sh`, but it can't find it. Maybe you should try reinstalling gitbash?

Comment: Woot! It was actually from gitbash. I should've figured it out as 'bash' was in the error log. Thanks a million mate :D.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this

```
ng new ProjectName --version 7
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Apparently gitbash was malfunctioning. I reinstalled it and now my app is 'revived' haha. Thanks again for the help.